# Will and Sarah's connection

Tags: plot-explanation, sense8

In Netflix series *Sense8*, during a pilot episode its shown that Angelica give birth to cluster which Will belongs, by this I am guessing she activate his cluster at that moment and he start to feel other members of his cluster and Jonas after that incident.

Then how did he connects with Sarah small girl who gone missing as shown during his childhood memory. He also encounters Mr.Whisper in one of the occasion.

Any explanation given for this? or will this be address in further seasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can gather all sensates were born sensates, which is why people in the same cluster have the same birthday and take their first breaths together. It isn't until later when someone activates their connection to their other selves in the cluster that they become aware of them, which is what Angelica does. Will and Sarah are both sensates, who made eye contact with each other when they were children hence their connection, to one another, even though he is still unaware of the rest of his cluster, or knows what is happening. He doesn't make eye contact with Whispers or Jonas until he his older. A similar thing happens between Riley and Yrsa in Iceland when Riley was still a child. Yrsa made eye contact with her at some point which is what connected them and then used that connection to try and keep her safe from Whispers and the Biologic Preservation Organization. So even though both Will and Riley were unaware of the rest of the cluster, it is shown that they still have some sensate abilities.

Comment: Totally forgot about Riley... Need to re watch season again... :)